# With Nix, how can I specify Haskell dependencies with profiling enabled?

Tags: haskell, nix

I was trying like this initially:

```
nix-shell -p "haskell.packages.ghc821.ghcWithPackages (p: with p; [text hspec lens])" -j4 --run 'ghc Main.hs -prof
```

Then GHC told me

```
Main.hs:4:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Control.Lens’
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘lens-4.15.4’?
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Searching around the web I found this: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/22340

So it seems I won't be able to download from the cache. But that's okay, if at least I can build the profiled variants locally.

Can I do that somehow simply by modifying the nix expression given to `-p` slightly?

Then at this point in writing this question, I remembered this resource: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/bd6ba7/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/lib.nix

Where I found `enableLibraryProfiling`. So I tried:

```
nix-shell -p "haskell.packages.ghc821.ghcWithPackages (p: with p; [text hspec (haskell.lib.enableLibraryProfiling lens)])" -j4 --run 'ghc Main.hs -prof'
```

Which got me to a new error:

```
src/Control/Lens/Internal/Getter.hs:26:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Functor.Contravariant’
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘contravariant-1.4’?
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
26 | import Data.Functor.Contravariant
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So if I could map over all packages to `enableLibraryProfiling` on them, then I guess this could work. But my nix knowledge doesn't quite extend that far at the moment. How could I do that? And is this even the correct path to pursue?

Comment: You can probably define a function that includes its argument as a package with profiling. You might also just want to do it the slow, repetitive way in a `shell.nix` file instead of specifying everything on the command line.

Comment: For whomever might end up here from Google: https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#how-to-build-with-profiling-enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With further snooping around in `nix-repl` and some helpful pointers from ElvishJerricco on #reflex-frp at FreeNode, I was able to construct this, which seems to work:

`$ nix-shell -p "(haskell.packages.ghc821.extend (self: super: {mkDerivation = expr: super.mkDerivation (expr // { enableLibraryProfiling = true; });})).ghcWithPackages (p: with p; [text hspec lens])" -j4 --run 'ghc Main.hs -prof'`

Comment: As it turns out, I may need to sneak in `-fprof-auto` somewhere in there.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a simple approach that I'm working into a largest blog post on Haskell development using Nix. For now, here's the text of just the profiling section:

Nix makes this fairly easy. First, we add the following to a `~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix`:

```
{
  packageOverrides = super: let self = super.pkgs; in
  {
    profiledHaskellPackages = self.haskellPackages.override {
      overrides = self: super: {
        mkDerivation = args: super.mkDerivation (args // {
          enableLibraryProfiling = true;
        });
      };
    };
  };
}
```

Now in the project we want to profile, we create a new `profiling-shell.nix`:

```
let nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
    orig = nixpkgs.pkgs.profiledHaskellPackages.callPackage ./default.nix {};
in (nixpkgs.pkgs.haskell.lib.doBenchmark orig).env
```

Almost identical to our normal `shell.nix`, except for the usage of `profiledHaskellPackages`, which we just defined globally. Now, an invocation of `nix-shell profiling-shell.nix` will rebuild *every* dependency in our project with profiling enabled. The first time this is done it will take quite a long time. Luckily this doesn't corrupt our Nix store - a vanilla `nix-shell` does seem to present us with our regular dependencies again, without redownloading or rebuilding.

**WARNING:** A `nix-collect-garbage -d` will wipe away all the custom-built libs from our Nix Store, and we'd have to build them again if they're needed.

If we're writing a library, the closest executable on hand that we could profile would be our benchmark suite. To do that:

- Add `-prof` and `-fprof-auto` to our benchmark's GHC options
- Regenerate `default.nix`
- Enter our profiling shell: `nix-shell profiling-shell.nix`
- `cabal configure --enable-library-profiling --enable-benchmarks`
- `cabal build`
- `dist/build/projname/projname-bench +RTS -p`
- Look at the produced `projname-bench.prof` file

Based on the results, we can make code changes, remove the profiling options, regenerate `default.nix`, and benchmark as usual in our normal Nix Shell.

Comment: https://www.fosskers.ca/#orgc7fbdab I'm guessing this is the blogpost? :)

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski here is the safer link: https://www.fosskers.ca/blog/nix-en.html

Comment: Link is broken.